# Sequence search using arrays in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, search, sequence

So, i have the following 2 arrays with me:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,4,1,2,5,1,3,2,4,5,11,23,24,51,72,5,91,19,0,1,2,4,2,3,45,3,2,1,2,6,7,56,78,354,3,2,1,0,111,15,1,2,3,5,6,4,7,3,8,910,678]
```

I need to search array A (in exactly same sequence) in array B using Python. I have tried 2 different ways to approach this problem. The first method resulted in index error which i could not resolve at all. The second method got me the expected result in the form of a binary answer, True/False. I'm out of ideas right now. Please help me approach this problem in a suitable manner.

```py
#one of the attempts that i made
from collections import Counter
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,4,1,2,5,1,3,2,4,5,11,23,24,51,72,5,91,19,0,1,2,4,2,3,45,3,2,1,2,6,7,56,78,354,3,2,1,0,111,15,1,2,3,5,6,4,7,3,8,910,678]
print (a,b)

def string_conv(array):
    string = ''
    for i in range(len(array)):
        string += str(array[i])
    return string

a = string_conv(a)
b = string_conv(b)

print (a,b)

def array_check(string, substring):
    c = Counter(string)
    for char in substring:
        if c[char] > 0:
            c[char] -= 1
        else:
            return False
    return True

print (array_check(a, b))
```

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You may show your attempts and the errors involved, along with your desired output. I guess you want the index, since you suggest you don't want just `True`/`False`.

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Simply dumping your problem and asking for a solution is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Actually i'm very new to programming, so, i'm not quite familiar with usage of stack overflow. I'll definitely keep this in my mind from next time.

Comment: @dspencer yes, actually i need the index where sequence match starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more elegant way of doing this but this should work:

```
for i in range(len(b) - len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if b[i + j] == a[j]:
            if j == len(a) - 1:
                print("Found it!")
            else:
                continue
        else:
            break
```

Comment: The index of where it starts is the value of i when the print() statement runs

Comment: Okay. So, if i use an identifier to store 'j' after the print statement and print it after the loop it should work right? I mean will it give me the index from where match starts or the index where match ends?

Comment: You want to store the value of i, which will be equal to the index of the start of the match at the print statement.